# Align text based on the decimal dot if the number of decimals is not the same

Tags: android, alignment

I get miscellaneous decimal values from the API. They may look like this 123.45, 0.12345678.

The format rule which I cannot change is like this:
1. if value <0, then have 8 decimal places
2. if value >0, then have 2 decimal places

Now, I cannot align the number based on the decimal dot. No matter if I align center, left or right. I always get something like this (aligned right)

```
       123.45
   0.12345678
         1.23
1234.12345678
```

Ideally, I need alignment like this

```
 123.45
   0.12345678
   1.23
1234.12345678
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: you add some whitespaces but you will need to check the largest number to see hown many spaces you will need - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862975/how-to-put-space-character-into-a-string-name-in-xml -- you may need to convert to string

Comment: Just pad your string to the right using a space as the padding character. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612866/java-string-padding-with-spaces

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi We don't have `StringUtils` in Android, but it's a good lead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using two separate text view in layout. One for decimal value and second for other.

Comment: @sandalone -- you can also use a table